# Tiny_mce.js "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined" for forecolor, backcolor buttons

Tags: javascript, tinymce, textcolor

I've been trying to configure TinyMCE Editor to display the forecolor and backcolor buttons for the textcolor plugin all day.

I have textcolor in my list of plugins and |,forecolor,backcolor,| in my theme_advanced_buttons2 setting.  I'm using TinyMCE 4.0.?

There is a space for the buttons, but the icons don't display -- all the others do, just not forecolor or backcolor.  When I inspect the element in Chrome, I see that the element is there:

```
<a role="button" id="id_text_forecolor" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_forecolor" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" aria-labelledby="id_text_forecolor_voice" title="" tabindex="-1">
<span class="mceIcon mce_forecolor"></span>
<span class="mceVoiceLabel mceIconOnly" style="display: none;" id="id_text_forecolor_voice"></span>
</a>
```

But when I click the button, the console displays this error, which happens in tiny_mce.js:1

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

Everything else in TinyMCE works fine.  I'm using Django and the Django-TinyMCE app, in case that makes a difference, tho I can't imagine why it would.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the current environment you're having the bug. However, my issue was with a tinyMCE plugin, using the same API. I experienced the same uncaught exception. I found the issue was that the parent createSplitButton() call lacked an onClick property. When tinyMCE tries to handle a click on the parent button, it fails with this error. My solution was to use jQuery (already loaded on page) to find the mceLast element, and trigger a click on it, which "shortcuts" the button that's supposed to open.

I wanted to make sure this error wasn't causing a major UX faux-pas: having the tinyMCE plugin button not do anything (& throw an error)!

```
control = e.createSplitButton( "plugin_button",
           {       
                title: "My Plugin",
                image: 'image.png',
                onclick: function  () {
                            jQuery("#content_"+name+"_open").closest('td').trigger('click')
                            return false;        
            }
});
```

name is the callback inside of tinyMCE.create() -> createControl(name,mgr)

Comment: This was the response I got to the issue, submitted to the Django-TinyMCE repo on Github: "In django-tinymce, we can't find textcolor plugin. But in tinymce, we can.  If you want to use this function, you have to modify that plugin yourself."  

My solution was to use the Redactor widget instead. https://github.com/mazelife/django-redactor